# Get Path and exe name

Tags: c#, windows

i need to display a path and name of all executable (application like MSWord, OpenOffice etc for word files) that can open Word and Acrobat Reader file. How can i do this?

It should work on windows xp , 7 ,8 , 2008

I want to find out the **path of all the applications** suitable to open the implied file types.

Can we use registry files for that.

Comment: Please revise your wording. In particular, the statement "executable file that can run Word software (...) in text file" is not clear to me.

Comment: [Getting File Associations using Windows API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536634/getting-file-associations-using-windows-api)

Comment: Alternatively, please consider rewriting your question: Do you actually want to find out the path of applications suitable to open the implied file types, or do you just want to open files of the implied types (without actually getting to know what applications are used to do so)?

Comment: You almost certainly are doing this the wrong way. Open the documents with Process and UseShellExecute = true

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to open the file using the default program just open it.

I.e.

```
Process.Start(@"c://file.pdf");
```