# Win10 ShellExecute to open a file always returns success even when failing to do so

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-10

Ever since Windows 10 Microsoft apparently decided to be super fancy (read annoying) and bring up a "I don't know any application" dialog when attempting to open a file that the operating system does not know how to open.
The annoying thing is however that it still claims to the caller that it did in fact open the file / execute the command despite failing.

`ShellExecute(NULL, TEXT("open"), TEXT("C:\\unknown_file_type.xyz"), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL)`

It does not matter whether or not you specify "open" or NULL for the operation, nor does it change anything to use to (more convoluted) ShellExecuteEx like so:

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO sei;
ZeroMemory(&sei, sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO));
sei.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
sei.lpVerb = TEXT("open");
sei.lpFile = TEXT("C:\\unknown_file_type.xyz");
sei.nShow  = SW_SHOWNORMAL;
sei.fMask  = SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI;
bool ok = ShellExecuteEx(&sei);
```

In either case the return value will be 2A for the ShellExecute one and hInstApp will be 2A for the ShellExecuteEx variant which returns true.
Interestingly despite specifying SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI the stupid empty box of "hey how would you like to open this file I know nothing about, these are your 0 options" still shows...

How can one tell if Windows was actually able to open the file?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536634/getting-file-associations-using-windows-api) help? (ie, look before you leap)

Comment: This executes a verb ("open") on a file. It's not Windows which will "open" it or not, and the net result will not necessary be a file that was "opened" (whatever that means for this file and its type) by an "application". You should define exactly what you want to know.

Comment: The *"Open With"* dialog in Windows 10 is the same as the one in Windows 8. What's the specific change in Windows 10 that seems to annoy you?

Comment: Consider using `FindExecutable()` or similar API to see if the file extension is registered before then invoking `ShellExecute/Ex()` to open the file.

Comment: @IInspectable might have been the same crap ever since Windows 8. Noone ever really used the clusterf that is Windows 8

Answer (score -3):

If Windows was actually able to open the file, [There should be some applications which have registered for the file type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/app-registration#examples). And [OpenWithProgIds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-include-an-application-on-the-open-with-dialog-box) ensure applications appear in the Open With menu and dialog box. [The Default value of the file type's HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.extension subkey implies the default application but not always.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/fa-file-types#deleting-registry-information-during-uninstallation)

Comment: This doesn't even begin to answer the OP's actual question.